# Can't get views by insightPlaybackLocationType — YouTube Analytics API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api, analytics

So I'm using the 'google-api-client' gem with Rails, and I'm attempting to call the URL below in order to get video views by insightPlaybackLocationType. This is a call that appears to be allowable from the [Available Reports](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports%20Available%20Reports) documentation page.

Unfortunately, I found that I was not able to make this call by using the API Explorer tool provided by Google.

URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1beta1/reports?metrics=views&ids=channel==CHANNEL_ID&dimensions=day,insightPlaybackLocationType&filter=video==VIDEO_ID&start-date=2013-01-15&end-date=2013-01-16&start-time=1970-01-01

Result:

```
{
  :error=>
    {
      "errors"=>[
        {
          "domain"=>"global",
          "reason"=>"invalid",
          "message"=>"Unknown identifier (insightPlaybackLocationType) given in field parameters.dimensions."
        }
      ],
      "code"=>400,
      "message"=>"Unknown identifier (averageViewDuration) given in field parameters.dimensions."
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what extra data I can provide in the initial description of this bug, but as stated before I am making the call to the API with the Google::APIClient Ruby library. The actual code itself looks like this:

```
client.execute(
  :api_method => api.reports.query,
  :parameters => options
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the version to v1 not v1beta1.

The start-time parameter seems wrong to me. You already specified start-date

Check the API explorer:
http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DCHANNEL_ID&start-date=2012-12-15&end-date=2013-01-16&metrics=views&dimensions=day%252CinsightPlaybackLocationType&filters=video%253D%253DVIDEO_ID&_h=4&